# Remove the parent default window in ImGui

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, imgui

I used one of the examples from ImGui source code (D3d11), I want to remove the ugly default host window that has the title "Dear ImGui DirectX11 Example" (image attached) and only use my own created window (the red one). [image]

From the code I can see that it is created using this:

```
// Create application window
//ImGui_ImplWin32_EnableDpiAwareness();
WNDCLASSEXW wc = { sizeof(wc), CS_CLASSDC, WndProc, 0L, 0L, GetModuleHandle(NULL), NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, L"ImGui Example", NULL };
::RegisterClassExW(&wc);
HWND hwnd = ::CreateWindowW(wc.lpszClassName, L"Dear ImGui DirectX11 Example", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, 100, 100, 600, 600, NULL, NULL, wc.hInstance, NULL);
```

Comment: So what is the question? Just remove it.

Comment: Does your program use `main` or `WinMain`?  Is the subsystem (linker option) set to `console` or `windows`?

Comment: I'm using WinMain and it;s set to windows in settings

Comment: I can't just remove it because the smaller window is actually being rendered "inside" it by default

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is you can't, because the DirectX11 window is used to render the imgui content

But you can hide it !
mainly by removing the imgui window titlebar and making it fill the whole DirectX11 window, "blending" the two windows together.

to do so, just pass the *ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar* flag to the imgui window in ImGui::Begin() (and maybe also ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove and ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize depending on your needs)

and add the *ImGui::SetNextWindowPos()* and *ImGui::SetNextWindowSize()* instructions just before ImGui::Begin() to place the imgui window at the top left corner and adjust its size to the DirectX11 window

ultimately, you should have something like that :

```
ImGuiWindowFlags window_flags = 0;
window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoTitleBar;
window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoMove;
window_flags |= ImGuiWindowFlags_NoResize;

while(...) {

    ...

    ImGui::SetNextWindowPos(ImVec2(0.0f, 0.0f)); // place the next window in the top left corner (0,0)
    ImGui::SetNextWindowSize(ImGui::GetIO().DisplaySize); // make the next window fullscreen
    ImGui::Begin("imgui window", NULL, window_flags) // create a window

    ...
}
```